# duplicateActiveSheet() not working with getSheetByName()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I could easily being doing something wrong but when using a blank sheet and Google App Script to duplicate the active sheet obtained with `getSheetByName()`, I get a TypeError.

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  if (ss !== null) {
    Logger.log(ss.getName()); // log: Sheet1
    Logger.log(ss.getSheetName()); // log: Sheet1
    Logger.log(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName()); // log: Sheet1
    ss.duplicateActiveSheet(); // TypeError: Cannot find function duplicateActiveSheet in object Sheet.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `duplicateActiveSheet()` is a [spreadsheet method](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#duplicateActiveSheet()), not a sheet method.

Modify your code like below :

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  if (sh !== null) {
    sh.activate();// make this sheet active
    Logger.log(sh.getName()); // log: Sheet1
    ss.duplicateActiveSheet();
  }
}
```

You could easily avoid such errors using the autocomplete feature in the script editor.

Just type a period (.) after the variable and you'll see all the available methods using "control space" on your keyboard.

[image]

Comment: Right, I keep forgetting the `: Sheet` is the return type and not the Class.